# Cross-browser HTML5 Drag and Drop JSON DataTransfer fails

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, xss, html5-draggable

I came to notice that for some reason it is not possible to transfer data from chrome to firefox or viceversa through a draggable object when the mime is set to `application/json`.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/n7N9p/4/

(Open that link in both, chrome and firefox and try dragging the JSON draggable from one browser to the other).

With that I have tested dragging the draggable in different scenarios:

1. From CHROME to CHROME via *text* **works**.
2. From CHROME to CHROME via *application/json* **works**.
3. From CHROME to CHROME INCOGNITO via *text* **works**.
4. From CHROME to CHROME INCOGNITO via *application/json* **works**.
5. From FIREFOX to FIREFOX via *text* **works**.
6. From FIREFOX to FIREFOX via *application/json* **works**.
7. From FIREFOX to FIREFOX PRIVATE WINDOW via *text* **works**.
8. From FIREFOX to FIREFOX PRIVATE WINDOW via *application/json* **works**.
9. From CHROME to FIREFOX via *text* **works**.
10. From CHROME to FIREFOX via *application/json* **does not work**.
11. From FIREFOX to CHROME via *text* **works**.
12. From FIREFOX to CHROME via *application/json* **does not work**.

Why does (only) 10 and 12 fail?

Is this a bug or security feature? If it is a security feature, then why is it insecure? How come 3, 4, 7 and 8 are not considered insecure? Why does it always work with the mime set to `text`?

Comment: **See also:*** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json

Answer (score 1):

> Why does (only) 10 and 12 fail?

`application/json` can be serialized to text if the browser knows the source

> How come 3, 4, 7 and 8 are not considered insecure?

The data is transferred from client to client, not client to server

> Why does it always work with the mime set to text?

The `setData` method of the `dataTransfer` object accepts text and dataURLs

**References**

- [HTML5 Drag and Drop in IE10 PPB2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/27/html5-drag-and-drop-in-ie10-ppb2.aspx)
- [Draggable attribute | property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772927)
- [Example of the setData Method](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/setDataEX.htm)